# ADODB Recordset not editable when using Access as backend, works fine with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I've got a simple MS Access 2013 form with some text boxes, each of whose Control Source is set to fields in an ADODB recordset. The recordset may come from either a table in the current accdb project or as the result of a SQL Server stored procedure; this is set by selecting a radio button on the form.

I've confirmed that each of the two recordsets are updateable in vba code but when I use the form it will only allow me to edit fields returned from the SQL Server option; the Access option displays records but acts as if the text box is locked when I attempt to edit it.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub cmdLoadData_Click()
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

With rst
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
End With

Select Case BackendOptions
    Case 1
        ' Access
        With rst
            .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
            .Open "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Birthday FROM tblADOTest"
        End With

    Case 2
        ' SQL Server
        Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection

        With cn
            .ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};" & _
                "Server=<the server name>;" & _
                "Database=<the database name>;" & _
                "Trusted_Connection=yes;"

            .Open
        End With

        With rst
            .ActiveConnection = cn
            .Open "EXEC dbo.GetTestData"
        End With
End Select

Set Me.Recordset = rst
End Sub
```

The stored procedure runs the same SQL as the inline string I'm using for Access.

Any ides on how to make the Access option editable?

Answer (score 0):

helped me solve a similar problem using this:
.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection